# Is there any way to develop an bluetooth device makes pop-up in a mobile device without making a mobile application?

Tags: android, bluetooth

What I wonder is just literally same as the title.
I'm considering to make a accessory for a mobile device but i need simple pop-up with URL link when some conditions are met.

Can i do this with basic operation of android framework?

Answer (score 0):

This used to be possible with beacons and the Nearby Notifications API but this functionality [has been deprecated](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/10/discontinuing-support-for-android.html).

You will have to develop an application for that.